# How to get all values from combobox selected record?

Tags: javascript, extjs, combobox, record

I've a combobox which returns 10 values from DB;

```
Ext.define('Iso3Combo', {
    extend:'',
    xtype:'iso3combo',

    requires: [
        'Ext.data.proxy.Ajax',
        'Ext.data.reader.Json'
    ],

    name: iso3
    fieldLabel: iso3,
    displayField:'iso3', // takes from DB 
    valueField:'id', // takes from DB
    store: {
        proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            url: ...getUrl() + '/country/list',
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                rootProperty: 'data'
            }
        },
        autoLoad: true
    },
    queryMode: 'local',
    autoLoad:true,
    bind: '{currRec.iso3}',
    listeners: {
                        fn: function () {
                          console.log('isocombo listeners...');
                        },
                        select: this.getIso3,
                        change: this.getIso3,
                        scope: this
                    }
});
```

As you will notice above; `combobox`'s displayed content is `iso3` and gets `id` as primary key. Therefore I can not change valueField. So tried this function to reach some other value for that selected combobox record;

```
getIso3: function () {
        var me = this;

        // var rec = me.getSelectedRecords(); //says getSelectedRecords is not a function

        var country = me.down('[name=iso3]').getValue(); // returns 'id'
        // var isoCode = rec.data.iso3; //Couldn't be success to verify if I get correct value..
```

How can i be able to load all values of DB from selected combobox record and select one of them?

Comment: `console.log(combo.getSelection());`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use [`combobox.getSelection()`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.2/classic/Ext.form.field.ComboBox.html#cfg-selection) or `combobox.getSelectedRecord()`. This both method will return you selected record. Or inside of [`select`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.2/classic/Ext.form.field.ComboBox.html#event-select) event you will get selected `record` in second `parameter` so also you can get `iso3` value like this `record.get('iso3')`.

Here is an **[FIDDLE](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2c12)**, I have created a demo using `form` and `combobox`. This will help you or guide you to solve  your problem.

I am using this **[COUNTRY JSON](https://paulund.co.uk/list-countries-json)**.

**Code Snippet**

```
// The data store containing the list of Country
var country = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    fields: ['iso3', 'id'],
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: 'countryList.json',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            rootProperty: 'countrylist'
        }
    },
    autoLoad: true
});

// Create form  with the combo box, attached to the country data store
Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
    title: 'Country List Example with ComboBox',
    bodyPadding: 10,
    items: [{
        xtype: 'combo',
        fieldLabel: 'Choose Country',
        store: country,
        queryMode: 'local',
        displayField: 'iso3',
        valueField: 'id',
        listeners: {
            select: function (field, record) {
                Ext.Msg.alert('Success', `Selected country <br> iso3 : <b>${record.get('iso3')}</b> <br> id : <b>${record.get('id')}</b>`);
            }
        }
    }],
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    buttons: [{
        text: 'Get Combo Value/Record on button click',
        handler: function () {
            var record = this.up('form').down('combo').getSelectedRecord();
            if (record) {
                Ext.Msg.alert('Success', `Selected country <br> iso3 : <b>${record.get('iso3')}</b> <br> id : <b>${record.get('id')}</b>`)
            } else {
                Ext.Msg.alert('Info', 'Please select contry first.. :)');
            }
        }
    }]
});
```

Comment: That's it! Such a perfect explanation!! Thanks a lot dear @Njdhv

Comment: Dear @Njdhv I got an error! I've defined a class which extends from `window`: `Ext.define('MyApp.view.weather.SettingsWindow', {
    extend: 'MyApp.view.weather.BaseWindow',
    xtype: 'settingswindow',` . So I've wrote the selection line as this way: `        var rec = this.up('settingswindow').down('citycombo').getSelectedRecord();
`  but gives error: `Cannot read property 'down' of undefined`

Comment: Is your `combobox` inside the same window?

Comment: No it has defined in another class and using by `xtype` config.

Comment: So you can provide `itemId` or `name` config to that `combobox` and use like this `Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#itemIdOfCombo')[0]` or `Ext.ComponentQuery.query('[name=nameOFCombo]')[0]`. This will return you the same combo.

Comment: Exactyl!! Now I can reach whole data of that record. And reached to that specific value with this code; `var countryDesc  = rec.data.description;
` and all works =) Thanks a lot dear @Njdhv

Comment: hearty welcome @NuriEngin. you can also use like this `record.get('description')`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163376/discussion-between-nuri-engin-and-njdhv).

Answer (score 0):

```
handler: function () {
   var selectionmodel=this.up().down('multiselect');
    var values=selectionmodel.values;
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post.  Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: Please read "[answer]". It helps more if you supply an explanation why this is the preferred solution and explain how it works. We want to educate, not just provide code.